# Print inside print php

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

How do i print INSIDE the defined tag?
When it ouputs this code, the_title() gets printed OUTSIDE (before) the h1 tag..

My code is:

```
        <?php 
            if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) {
                print '<p>HEY</p>';
            }
            else {
                print '<div class="page-header row full"><h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline">', the_title() ,'</h1></div>';
            }
        ?>
```

i have already tried:

```
        <?php 
            if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) {
                print '<p>HEY</p>';
            }
            else {
                print '<div class="page-header row full"><h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline">'. the_title() .'</h1></div>';
            }
        ?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try echo instead of print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like below:

```
<?php if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
    <p>HEY</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="page-header row full"><h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or use `get_the_title()`(which returns the title value) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print "....".get_the_title().".....";`

The methods "the_xxxx" print the value, the methods "get_the_xxx" returns the value.

Answer (score -1):

try echo instead of print

```
echo - can output one or more strings

print - can only output one string, and returns always 1
```

Comment: The problem is that the function itself prints its result instead of returning it. The usage of `echo` would not make any difference.